# FTK-latitude and longitude are not valid, I do not understand

Tags: location, latitude-longitude

[image]

A video file property shows latitude and longitude. I have no idea about how to read it, and I thought they are not in the normal format?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid pasting screenshots. Paste actual code, that can be read well and searched, so others can find it.
Read [this guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on further markdown formatting tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows user, using Perl & ExifTool can read the exif data in picture, which include GPS data with correct format, otherwise you need to convert it first. cause GPS stored in picture exifdata cannot be used directly without convertion.